# How can I let the Android 2.2 browser just stream the video instead of downloading the video from html?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I'm running into a funny problem. I have a html file where a video is embedded. When I'm launching this html from my mobile with Android 2.3, it just streams fine, I can see whole video from the android browser. But when I try to do the same from my other android with 2.2 version, it tries to download the video instead of steaming.

How can I let the Android 2.2 browser just stream the video instead of downloading the video from html?

The media player in the html file used is JW player, and the html file with video is hosted on bitsontherun website.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android 2.2 phone probably doesn't understand the plugin (jw player is a flash video player if memory serves).
Does the 2.2. phone have the flash pluing installed and set to use? In the webview make sure it is allowed to use the plugins as well:

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks Pulsar, yes, the plugin needs to be enabled when i'm launching WebView from my app for all Android versions. However, the Flash Player plugin comes for android is dependent on CPU memory (min 256 MB) but my android 2.2 mobile has only 140 MB RAM, so I cannot play the video I desired. Thanks for your help.